# Use of hyphen in "Synthetic free-fiber insulation"?

Tags: hyphens

On a jacket care label I found this sentence:

> "Synthetic free-fiber insulation"

Is this correct use of hyphen? (given that it should mean that the fiber in the insulation is free from synthetic)

If so, would there be any ambiguity in the sentence without the hyphen? And wouldn't it make more sense to write "Synthetic-free fiber insulation"?

My initial reaction when I read this was that the insulation in my jacket was made of synthetic "free-fiber". (Admittedly, that's not a thing.)

Comment: It's not very idiomatic to attach the ***-free*** suffix here, but I'm sure what you mean is *synthetic fibre-free insulation* (insulation which is free from / lacks synthetic fibre).

Comment: Your initial reaction was good.  There is such a thing.  The insulation consists of free fibers -- loose material.  Without the hyphen, it would seem to mean synthetic insulation, free insulation, and fiber insulation.  With the hyphen, we know "free" describes the fibers, not the insulation itself.  That gives us synthetic insulation made from fibers that are not bound to each other.  Your second thought is possible, but it would more likely be labeled as "all-natural" rather than "synthetic-free".  It's not a reasonable given.